# What type of exercise will cause growth retardation on my body.?

Tags: muscle, muscle-recovery, muscle-gain, growth

I like to workout a lot(once two hours a day) for a whole week and people keep warning me on my height and growth because I'm 17. Which exercise will cause growth retardation and height loss on my body..?

Comment: Um........none?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=myth%20of%20stunting%20growth%20working%20out

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking there is not "one exercise" that will cause "growth retardation". It is merely the type of training that you are doing that ***may*** influence the body in his development.

If you are young your bonestructure is not as solid as it will be when you are grown up and its prone to alter its form and direktion to grow with acting and repeating force. 
The fact that young bones are more flexible and mellow, is also the reason why children don't get fractures that easily.

The higher the force on the bone and more frequent it occurs the more it will create a reaktion of change in the structure. You have to imagine that the muscle is connected to the bone by tendons. And when the muscle is flexed it puls the tendon which pulls the bone. If this is repeated often with heavy force and the bone is still not fully grown it will adapt to this new environment and purpose in different ways that may inhibit the growth potential eg. in hight.

This is why people should not lift too heavy weights until they are almost fully grown. If you want to work out at a younger age you should train the muscular endurance.

It is not scientificly said at what age you are save to start with heavy weight exercises. 18 is the average number that is promoted when you can work out heavy but it differs in reality and depends on how fast you develope. Also it is said that you are fully grown when you are 21...

I hope i could help you.
Best regards